# Sampling alias phase when undersampling

Tags: sampling, sine, aliasing

I have to measure the sum of the magnitude of two sinusoidal signals and I think I can exploit the undersampling method in order to superimpose the alias of the sinusoid at the higher frequency over the one at the lower frequency (that are just two deltas in the spectrum). I have some doubts about the phase of the alias, it remains the same of the original signal?

Comment: You need to be more specific about the details of your problem. This is super vague. Draw some pictures. Put down some numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The aliased signal's phase has no relationship with the original signal but that doesn't really matter. If your ADC has no analogue bandwidth losses at the high input frequency then the aliased signal's amplitude will be the same as the original. The magnitude of the sum is therefore what it would be if you summed the two original signals.

One proviso, the sampling rate and the original HF signal should not coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the observed phase is related to the sample rates and the aperture time of the sampler. The inverse of the aperture corresponds to a null in the sampled output. If you are undersampling, we assume that you are operating in a region that is less than the 1st null, hence the phase of the alias is positive.
e.g. if you sample a signal at w1*t + phi1, and w1 < ws/2 ( ws = sampling frequency) , then the observed phase is w1*t + phi1.
If you sample w2*t + phi2, and ws/2